# g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option

Tags: swig

I am using swig to implement C++ code with Python.
There seems to be some issue compiling the dynamic module.

```
g++ -fpic -c jmotif.h repair_wrap.cxx repair.cpp -/Users/U374235/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/neuralnetwork/python3.5.6/
```

The result is that I'm getting an error -

```
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-/Users/U374235/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/neuralnetwork/python3.5.6/'
```

I believe this issue is being caused due to my giving swig the wrong Python.h header address

Comment: It looks like that should be `-IC:/Users/...`

Comment: @molbdnilo what does IC stand for?

Comment: `-I` means "look for Include files in this directory". `C` is where I'm convinced your Anaconda installation is.

Comment: @molbdnilo It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My syntax was incorrect. I should have written -

```
g++ -fpic -c jmotif.h repair_wrap.cxx repair.cpp -IC:/Users/U374235/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/neuralnetwork/python3.5.6/
```